# Native video preview iOS

Tags: ios

Does iOS expose the native video preview with Play button as seen before playing video's in Safari? I would like to do this natively within my app. At the very least, I would like to just be able to use the play button, then just place in a view, and when it is clicked, replace that view with the video view. Is this possible?

[image: Preview image]

Answer (score 0):

The play button is not exposed by iOS, make your own, or use a webview.